# How to connect by mobile broadband?

Tags: connection, mobile-broadband

How I can connect with mobile broadband as Reber Quick in Iraqi Kurdistan Regional? It's not working in Ubuntu 12.04. It's user and password is: reber

Answer (score 1):

**Connecting AriaNet (or ReberQuick) to your Ubuntu box**

1. Connect your device to your computer.
2. Go to the Network applet, right click on it and select (Edit Connections).

   [image: Edit connections]
3. Click on the Mobile Broadband tab.

   [image: Mobile broadband tab]
4. Click on forward.

   [image: Setup broadband]
5. Select Iraq, and click forward.

   [image: Select Iraq]
6. Select (I can't find my provider, and I wish to enter it manually), then write the name of your provider (either Arianet or Reber Quick), then click forward.

   [image: Choose Arianet]
7. Now, click on Apply and you are almost done :)

   [image: Apply button]
8. Enter your username and password, then click on Apply.

   [image: Username and password]
9. Now your connection is ready, and you can simply select it by clicking on your Network applet.

   [image: Network applet]

[(Source)](http://amanj-kos.blogspot.com/2010/12/connecting-arianet-or-reberquick-to.html)

Don't forget to checklist connect automatically